# Value cannot be null or empty.\r\nParameter name: name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

when i go to cshtml page this error occur:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

in my cshtml code :

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.Label("Model", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
  <div class="col-md-8">
     @Html.Editor("Model")
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

but on the other hand if i change my code in `@Html.Editor("PropertyModel")`

it is working perfectly no error occur .

### UPDATE:

in my model:

```
public class PropertyAssign {
        public int PropertyAssignId { get; set; }

        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }


        public DateTime AssignDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: Show us your model

Comment: Because you are not passing a model to the view.

Comment: i am passing model to the view @model TITHR.Models.Property.PropertyAssign

Comment: @Rob  check update section

Comment: could be that `Model` is reserved word

Comment: What is it that your trying to generate an input for? If its for the property `Model`, then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model)` And show how you pass the model to the view. It needs to be `return View(x);` where `x` is an instance of `PropertyAssign`

Comment: @StephenMuecke @Html.Editor(m => m.Model) don't you think it should be @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model)

Comment: @VarunVasishtha, Yes :)

Comment: The reason your current usage does not work is `ViewData` contains a property `Model` (which is the model you passed to the view, and in you case, you have not passed a model so its `null`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke  i want to set value by ajax request , like this way $("#Model").val("BMW 0023") and then save to hit the controller action method with "PropertyAssign  model binding"

Comment: Then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model)` - it will create an input with `id="Model"` and it will also bind to the value of property `Model` (even if the model is `null`)

Comment: well, on the other hand if i want set data ViewBag that time should be use @Html.Editor("Model" ,(string)ViewBag.Model ) .is it work?

Comment: Why in the world would you use `ViewBag` (or `Editor()` for that matter)? Just use `@EditorFor(m => m.Model)` or `TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)` You should always be using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the exception is thrown is that the `HtmlHelpers` inspect `ViewData` to get the values to bind to. `ViewData` is typeof [ViewDataDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) which contains a property `Model` (which is the model you pass to the view).

In your case, you do not return a model to the view so `ViewData.Model` is `null` and the exception is thrown.

To solve this, use the strongly typed `EditorFor(m => m.Model)` (or `TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)` which you should be doing in any case. Even if you do not pass a model to the view, this will still generate the correct html without throwing an exception.

```
<input type="text" name="Model" id="Model" value="" />
```

but its best practice to pass a model anyway, so your controller method should be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  return View(new PropertyAssign());
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, after reading this, when I code a strongly typed helper for nullable datetime, like so `@Html.TextBoxFor((model => model.TimeSheetWeekToDate.HasValue ? model.TimeSheetWeekToDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datepicker TimeSheetWeekToDate" })` I still get the error that name is null?

Comment: @transformer, You need to as a new question with the relevant details, but you cannt use a conditional statement as a expression in a `HtmlHelper` method. And what you have show does not makes sense anyway - it would be just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeSheetWeekToDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { .... })`

Answer (score 3):

I've tryed this case and it's very strange, but there is some problem with the identifier of your Model property with usage of @Html.Editor() helper.

```
@Html.Editor("Model") // throws an exception
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model) // works fine
```

Maybe in this context the meaning of Model is the whole model, which is passed to the view, not the single property. But when I've changed the identifier of the Model property to some other, for example SomeModel, everything is fine.

```
@Html.Editor("SomeModel") // works fine
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeModel) // works fine
```

So, the possible solutions are:

- to change the Editor helper you use or
- to change your property identifier

Answer (score 0):

write using your model name at the top like

```
@using projectNamespace.PropertyAssign
```

when using editor for your some property you can write like

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropertyName)
```

for text box its

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.PropertyAssign , new { @class = "release-prefix" @id = "prefix" })
```